# Skyrim DLC for ps4

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-dragonborn

I recently bought the Elder Scrolls 5 - SKyrim Special Edition for PS4 (the version on a disc).

I know that for the PS3 version there are 3 DLC's (Dawnguard, Dragonborn and Heartfire) [who can be found here](https://store.playstation.com/nl-be/grid/search-game/1?gameContentType=addons&platform=ps3&query=elder%20scrolls). Now I have the PS4 version and I would like to have the DLC's. But when adjusting the search parameters in the playstation store only content for the Elder Scrolls Online shows up [(as can be seen here)](https://store.playstation.com/nl-be/grid/search-game/1?gameContentType=addons&platform=ps4&query=elder%20scrolls).

So my question is: **Are there any DLC's for Skyrim on PS4?**
If they do exist where can I find them, and if they don't exist will they ever be available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skyrim Special Edition comes with all DLC already included. You don't need to buy it separately.

Comment: oh ok, I thought it was just build on a better engine

Comment: @Jorrit A better engine and all DLC. Gamers would rightfully screech at Bethesda if the studio would have tried to cash in twice for DLC. Essentially, the Special Edition is just Skyrim Legendary Edition ported to the Fallout 4 engine.

Comment: Actually, they both use Gamebryo, it's just been updated to the version used by FO4 and (more importantly for modding) been updated to a 64-bit executable.   Also, if you own Skyrim with all DLCs for PC, Special Edition is/was free on PC.  I'm not sure if Bethesda and Steam are still doing that one, but that's how I got mine.